# Thread-safe rand for C

Tags: c, random, thread-safety, pthreads

I have this very short program for dealing with thread-safety of C's `rand`. Is it a correct implementation?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} thread_safe_rand;

void thread_safe_rand_init(thread_safe_rand* tsr)
{
    if (tsr)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&tsr->mutex, NULL);
    }
}

void thread_safe_rand_free(thread_safe_rand* tsr)
{
    if (tsr)
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&tsr->mutex);
    }
}

int thread_safe_rand_get(thread_safe_rand* tsr)
{
    int ret;

    if (tsr)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&tsr->mutex);
        ret = rand();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&tsr->mutex);
        return ret;
    }
    else
    {
        abort();
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(10);
    thread_safe_rand tsr;
    thread_safe_rand_init(&tsr);
    printf("%d\n", thread_safe_rand_get(&tsr));
    thread_safe_rand_free(&tsr);
}
```